# Is it possible to sign Git commits on a different computer?

Tags: digital-signature, pgp, git

I'm doing some development work on an untrusted computer. I'd like to sign my commits I make from it, but I don't want my personal PGP key to touch this computer. Or maybe I'm using a PGP smart card and I can't present it to the computer because of a lack of smart card reader.

Usually Git commit signing works by calling into the `gpg` executable on the local machine somehow. If I need to use a key that can't leave a computer, I'd do the commit from the computer that has the key. However, in this case, I can only make commits from this untrusted PC because it lives inside a private network and I can't get at the Git repository from outside.

I'd like to create a commit, then export some data object from the untrusted PC, bring it to the trusted PC, run a PGP command on this data, then bring the result back to the untrusted PC, and as a result the Git commit would become signed.

Is this possible and how would I set it up?

Comment: Don't know much about Git signing, so this might be a nonsense idea, but if you don't want to use your _personal_ PGP key for signing, can you create a separate PGP key specifically for this development work?

Comment: The smart way to do this is to have a hardware token like a Yubikey that keeps the private key used for your signatures, such that that token _is never directly readable by any general-purpose CPU at all_ and the signatures are performed off-board, by the smartcard, where even if the host system has been infected it can only _use_ the card while it's actively plugged in (and potentially, based on configuration, when the user is pushing a button to approve the signature operation), but not duplicate the key it contains for offline use.

Comment: (A Yubikey only needs a USB slot, not a smartcard reader). Mind, there's also gpg-agent support, which can be forwarded over SSH much in the same way a SSH agent can be forwarded.

Comment: See https://github.com/drduh/YubiKey-Guide?tab=readme-ov-file#remote-machines-gpg-agent-forwarding

Comment: "*export some data object from the untrusted PC, bring it to the trusted PC, run a command on this data, then bring the result back to the untrusted PC*" - if you can do that, it means that you actually do have access to the git repository from the trusted PC: just bring the entire repository! That's what *decentralised* version control is all about in git. You don't need to have access to the same remotes as the untrusted PC.

Comment: Is there some reason you can’t create a one-off key for this purpose? If you truly don’t trust the computer you’re working on, I would question whether you want your usual key associated with the commits generated there.

Comment: In a comment below you mention that, "the people [you're] working for don't trust [you] with their code except on their PC." You _really_ should add this information to your question since it's has a huge influence on the kinds of solutions that we can propose.

Comment: demand your employer provide you with a new PGP key.

Comment: If the people you're working for don't trust you with their code except on their PC, what makes you think they'd be fine with copying out arbitrary data from their PC to yours?

Comment: Off topic or perhaps relevant: why do you want/need to sign your commits? also, why do you want/need to sign them with your personal key instead of one generated ad-hoc?

Comment: Are you SSHing into this machine, or is it a separate machine without any network connection to your personal computer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an attempt to turn [cjs's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/275980/47325) into concrete steps.

1. `git log --oneline HEAD` to extract the guid of the commit you want to sign.
2. `git cat-file commit COMMIT_GUID > commit.txt` to generate a copy of the raw commit.  `commit.txt` has the change description and hashes, no actual code in it.
3. Transfer `commit.txt` to your trusted computer.
4. Run `gpg --armor --output commit.sig --detach-sig commit.txt` to generate a GPG signature in `commit.sig`.  I don't think `gpg` knows how git expects the signature to be embedded, so you have to do it manually.
5. Carefully create a new `signed-commit.txt` by starting with `commit.txt` and inserting `gpgsig`  followed by the contents of `commit.sig` as the last header.  Be careful about whitespace; experimentation may be required.
6. Transfer `signed-commit.txt` back to your untrusted computer you are editing.
7. Add the raw signed commit to the git repo.  This prints the hash you'll need next: `cat signed-commit.txt | git hash-object -w --stdin -t commit`.  (getting the newlines right here could be tricky; I don't want to use filters, as we have signed the file based on the binary data, but...)
8. `git update-ref refs/heads/master RAW_SIGNED_COMMIT_HASH` using the hash from step 7.

Then do a `git verify-commit HEAD` to see if something went wrong, and debug.

To debug this, do the entire work on your trusted computer.  Have a toy repo to work with and a toy commit.

Take an unsigned commit and do steps 1-5 on it.  Then use git tools to sign the commit with the same identity.  You can compare the `signed-commit.txt` to the `git cat-file commit SIGNED_COMMIT_GUID` and ensure they are binary identical.

If the signature differs, then something is wrong with either step 2 or 4; otherwise, there is something wrong with how we built `signed-commit.txt` from `commit.sig` and `commit.txt`.

You can then check steps 7-8 locally.  Step 7 should return the SIGNED_COMMIT_GUID if it is correct, and 8 should do nothing if you are already pointing at the signed commit.

Once this debugging is complete, what is left is the possibility of text file format differences or something going wrong in the transfer.

Comment: The first step is rather `git rev-parse HEAD` but you don't need it, `git cat-file commit HEAD` works fine. In step 7-8 , you can just merge them into `git update-ref refs/heads/master $(git hash-object -w --stdin < signed-commit.txt)` I guess.

Comment: @chx sure, but I tried not to assume you have a *nix shell (ie, I think all of the commands I provide are both *nix shell and windows compatible)

Comment: You should give `git hash-object` the `-t commit` option to ensure that you produce a commit object and not a generic blob object. You also probably want to give the filename to `git hash-object` rather than using `--stdin` because `--stdin` also implies `--no-filters`.

Comment: @cjs Given that we are getting the raw output and editing it, isn't no filters correct?  I guess the risk is that the text editor we use to build the object has the wrong newlines?  It is key that the file we sign is binary-identical to the file in the git repo without filters, right?

Comment: Since you're editing the output before returning it, it's a good idea to enable whatever checks you can when inserting the object into the database. Your example of wrong newlines is one obvious error that could happen (though `hash-object --stdin` appears to catch this error). I'm not clear on exactly what errors `--no-filters` allows through, but it seems unlikely that they are any errors you'd want in your Git database.

Comment: @cjs But the problem is that is if filters makes **any** changes at all, your signature is no longer valid.  Because we binary signed the version of the file that was unfiltered.  (Ok, not quite true; filters could reformat without changing the content of the PGP block).  Now, in theory, the commit.txt you started with should have had all rules applied to it.

Comment: You're right that the filters could change the data and invalidate the signature. (Even a reformat would invalidate the sig, actually.) But that produces an error that is actually easier to detect than other errors, since you'll see it immediately when you `git verify-commit`. Other errors may not be detected until you perform other operations. (For example, you won't see an error in a tree ID until you try to access the tree itself, so e.g., `git log` will work fine but `git log --patch` will fail with an error. Though that, admittedly, is one of the things _not_ checked by the filters.)

Comment: TLDR: We don't know exactly what the filters do (if anything) on commit objects, but if they detect a problem and make a change, we'll know about it immediately on verification, as opposed to finding out about a problem later during some other Git operation.

Comment: @cjs I believe Filters have already been applied to the "commit.txt" we are editing, and applying them twice is a logic error akin to unescaping a string twice?  We are trying to work with the raw content within the git database and inject a header to it, and are intentionally bypassing standard git tools to do so.  I'd be tempted to write a "git-inject-header REF header.txt" script that takes an arbitrary ref, grabs the raw text, injects the header.txt into the header, then pushes it back and returns the new guid; and that shouldn't apply filters or smudges.

Comment: I was thinking of the filters as a syntax check, where there's no issue with running the same syntax check as many times as you care to because it's idempotent. But I see where you're coming from: you're thinking of the filters as _modifying_ the data, which is likely correct for e.g. file objects. So possibly/probably the filters do nothing at all on commit objects.  ¶ So, probably using `--no-filter` is fine. Still, why not just drop that option anyway, since it can't cause any harm, and might do some good for commit objects?

Answer (score 23):

If you are working for hire, a solution is to create a new PGP key just for the process, and sign it with your normal key, and sign the commits with that. In the event that your employer actually earns your lack of trust, you can then disclaim that key.

Comment: What does "disclaim" mean, technically? (What's the effect of desclaiming?)

Comment: @PabloH Public keys are only worth anything as long as they can be actually linked to the person that is said to be controlling that key. Usually this is done via public key repositories. disclaiming a key usually means leaving an entry in "your" "this-is-my-key" place that says that a specific key is NOT connected to you (anymore) and should not be trusted

Comment: Note that reliable [key revocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_revocation) is a difficult task. Everything else in [PKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) is typically designed so that signature verification can be done offline as long as the verifier has access to the signature and a limited set of public root keys, but the cryptographic methods used to achieve this don't allow "un-signing" a key. The best you can do is sign a message effectively saying "sorry, this key is no longer valid", but that won't help if the verifier never gets that message.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen You can mitigate this risk by creating short-lived keys (e.g. a few days) so the time for misuse will be very short.

Answer (score 17):

Note that this answer takes into account your [comment on an answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/275966/is-it-possible-to-sign-git-commits-on-a-different-computer#comment573942_275967)
indicating that you cannot copy the code from the work machine you are
using (which I will call, using your personal viewpoint, the "untrusted
host") to a personal machine (the "trusted host") that holds your signing
key. (You really should update your question with this information since it
rules out a whole class of fairly obvious solutions.)

A [commit signature](https://git-scm.com/docs/signature-format#_commit_signatures) in Git is a signature over just the [Git commit
object](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects#_git_commit_objects) from the repo database.¹ Here's an example of signed commit
object data:

```
tree eebfed94e75e7760540d1485c740902590a00332
parent 04b871796dc0420f8e7561a895b52484b701d51a
author A U Thor <author@example.com> 1465981137 +0000
committer C O Mitter <committer@example.com> 1465981137 +0000
gpgsig -----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
 Version: GnuPG v1
 $
 iQEcBAABAgAGBQJXYRjRAAoJEGEJLoW3InGJ3IwIAIY4SA6GxY3BjL60YyvsJPh/
 HRCJwH+w7wt3Yc/9/bW2F+gF72kdHOOs2jfv+OZhq0q4OAN6fvVSczISY/82LpS7
 DVdMQj2/YcHDT4xrDNBnXnviDO9G7am/9OE77kEbXrp7QPxvhjkicHNwy2rEflAA
 zn075rtEERDHr8nRYiDh8eVrefSO7D+bdQ7gv+7GsYMsd2auJWi1dHOSfTr9HIF4
 HJhWXT9d2f8W+diRYXGh4X0wYiGg6na/soXc+vdtDYBzIxanRqjg8jCAeo1eOTk1
 EdTwhcTZlI0x5pvJ3H0+4hA2jtldVtmPM4OTB0cTrEWBad7XV6YgiyuII73Ve3I=
 =jKHM
 -----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

signed commit

signed commit message body
```

In the above, note that:

- The `$` is not part of the data, it highlights that that line consists of
  a single space.
- The "signed commit" and "signed commit message body" are the commit
  message.)
- The signature is (obviously) over the commit object data *excluding* the
  `gpgsig` field.

So if the people you're working for are ok with sending just the above
information (various hashes, commit author and committer names and e-mail
addresses, and the commit message) being sent to your trusted host you can
(in theory at least) sign the commits with your personal key. What you will
need to do is, as part of the commit process:

1. Have Git generate the commit object data like the above, less the
   `gpgsig` field. (This can be done with, e.g., `git cat-file commit <commit-ish>`, or you could even just generate it yourself as there's no
   special magic to it.) Note that this commit object data is itself not
   yet a commit; the commit hash (i.e., the name of the object in the
   database) cannot yet be calculated because the `gpgsig` field is also
   covered under the commit hash.
2. Send that information to your trusted host where you will somehow sign
   it in a secure way. (Be careful with this: merely `ssh`ing into your
   trusted host from the untrusted host gives you significant exposure to
   attacks from or on the untrusted host.) One way of doing this is to run
   `gpg --armor --output commit-data.sig --detach-sig commit-data.txt` and
   then adding this `commit-data.sig` output as a `gpgsig` field to
   `commit-data.txt`, matching the example above.
3. Return the commit object data with the newly-added `gpgsig` field to the
   untrusted host and then generate the commit object from that. One way of
   doing this is with `git hash-object -w -t commit commit-data.txt`, which
   will return the identifier (SHA-1 hash) of the commit object that this
   creates. (Note that this does not do much, if any, validity checking; in
   particular it will accept invalid parent and tree IDs that you will find
   out about only later when you try to make use of the commit.) You will
   likely also want to update a ref (branch) to include this new commit
   with something like `git update-ref refs/heads/main ID`.

(Further note: per Charles Duffy's comment below, it is technically not
even necessary to send the above information, but just the same hash of it
that PGP would generate and sign. But that is extra work that may or may
not be relatively simple, dependig on who's helping you, and it would also
preclude the ability to sign a chain of commits as mentioned below; you
would instead always have to return the signature for a commit and generate
that commit before you could generate the PGP hash to be signed for a child
commit.)

Note that this does not have to happen "all at once;" depending on how you
set up your system it's perfectly possible to start the process at work,
send the proposed commit object data to your personal system, go home, do
the signatures there, send them back, and create the actual commits when
you return to work, though this obviously could be somewhat slow and
awkward. More likely you would want to bring a trusted laptop into work and
simply switch between the two machines.

But I do believe it would also be possible to send a chain of commit
objects or commit object data to your trusted machine, sign each commit in
the chain (updating the `parent` field for each subsequent commit as you
go), and then return them all to be inserted into the Git database on the
untrusted machine.

The technicalities of doing this appear to be fairly difficult; it would
require a good knowledge of Git and custom software that connects to Git
itself (or, preferably, its code exposed as a library API), possibly some
reimplementation of parts of Git, and some trusted means of transferring
the commit object data from the untrusted to the trusted host. (You don't
need it to be trusted the other way around since you can verify the
signature on the commit object data when that is returned to your work.)
This is all complex enough that, though I can see where I would get started
on doing this, I think I will leave it as an exercise for the reader. :-/

(FWIW, though I don't have a lot of time to spend on this kind of thing
unless I were getting paid for it, if someone out there wants to start a
project to try to build tools to do this, feel free to contact me privately
via the e-mail address in my profile and I'll be happy to help out as best
I can—for free, of course, if the result is under an appropriate open
source licence.)

---

<sup>¹ It's worth nothing that this covers only the commit metadata, *not*
the directory tree or files themselves. The proof that those are correct is
dependent on the [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hashes that are referenced from the commit object.
SHA-1 [has not been considered secure](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/cryptanalysis_o.html) against well-funded attackers
since the mid-2000s. This can be mitigated by [using SHA-256
hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65874596/107294), but this is not the default and [is still considered
experimental functionality](https://git-scm.com/docs/hash-function-transition), though the format is not expected to
change in a backward incompatible way. Further, many (most?) remote repo
storage systems do not support SHA-256 hashes, so you cannot transfer
SHA-256 hashes through them.</sup>

Comment: Under the hood, even the commit doesn't need to be sent to the trusted machine -- just the padded hash of that commit (as extended by OpenPGP -- it's not derivable _just_ from the commit data). Signing a 100gb file with a smartcard doesn't send all 100gb of data over the wire to the card, f/e.

Comment: (Background: In a past life, I built a shim between OpenPGP -- Go's implementation, not the super-crufty GnuPG codebase -- and a corporate key escrow system; so I speak from firsthand experience when saying that this is very, _very_ possible).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's a good point, good enough that I've integrated a bit of it into my answer. Thanks!

Comment: A concrete set of git (ideally command-line) commands would improve this answer.  Ie, how to get the "raw" unsigned commit text via an explicit git command, how to generate the gpgsig using gpg command line tools, and how to take the gigsig included file and make a commit of it using git command-line tools.

Comment: For the first: `git cat-file commit COMMIT_GUID` gets you the raw commit (with tree guids and everything) you want to sign.

Comment: For the third, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064968/building-git-commit-objects-with-git-hash-object provides a framework for doing it.  That only leaves a command-line way to do the signature of the cat-file output.

Comment: And for the 2nd, I think `gpg --output commit.sig --detach-sig commit.txt` might do it.  Then you need to insert the commit.sig as the final header within the commit.

Comment: @Yakk Good point. And, ironically, I'd already myself written a program that does commit generation without using `git commit`. I've incorporated all your suggestions into my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @cjs I don't think commit-tree will do it, as I don't think it allows adding headers (like gpgsig).   https://security.stackexchange.com/a/276007/47325 is my best attempt (not actually tried, just reading docs) where we do a raw `git hash-object` on a properly formatted commit file and then `git update-ref` to attach it to HEAD.  It probably contains errors.

Comment: @Yakk Yes, you are correct. I misread one of the answers to which you linked because the code looked like it was emitting commit object data, but it was actually just a commit message with a vague resemblance to commit object data.

Answer (score 12):

If you have access to the remote repository from your trusted PC,you can fetch the usigned commits on your trusted PC, sign the commits, and then push them again. This will alter the commit hashes, so you will need to force-push or push them to a different branch.

You can use this command to sign the previous commit

```
git commit --amend --no-edit -S
```

[See this SO answer for more options](https://superuser.com/questions/397149/can-you-gpg-sign-old-commits)

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately it doesn't work for my usecase: the people I'm working for don't trust me with their code except on their PC, and I don't trust their PC.

Comment: ah. You should add that condition to the question, it makes a big difference. You would need to split the signing process in half - the "untrusted PC" would need to mangle the commit contents into something that cannot be transformed back into the commit, and your "trusted PC" would need to transform this mangled commit into a signature. I don't know enough about how Git signatures work to tell whether this is theoretically possible or not

Comment: One idea I had was to replace the `gpg` executable on the untrusted PC with a script that would echo its arguments to stdout, where I would take them, put them into the real `gpg` program on my other PC, and then bring the result back into the terminal. That sounds very hackish though, and I was wondering if anyone had solved the problem of security separation like this.

Comment: so your coworkers would be fine with the commit message being leaked to your "trusted PC"? Then you could externalize the signature creation like you described.

Comment: @Yogu, re: "how git signatures work" -- normal OpenPGP. You get a hash of the signature and its framing &c, and the key needs to sign that hash, same as most other mechanisms. (That means the whole message doesn't need to be sent over the wire -- just the fixed-length hash)

Comment: @Danya02 If you truly don't trust the PC, then any automated solution will not be safe because the untrusted PC could call the automated solution to sign anything. How would you know those hex-code arguments were really for a git commit?

Comment: @user253751 I guess in an absolute sense that's true. I was mainly concerned about non-targeted attacks like someone snooping at the root directory and noticing a GPG key of unknown value; whereas your attack would require someone deliberately messing with the signing setup.

Answer (score 0):

An option that seems the closest in spirit to what I want is to set up a `gpg-agent` program that would delegate the actual cryptography to a human.

When you use GPG to sign things, it talks to the `gpg-agent` to actually perform the operations with the private key. That way, the `gpg-agent` can remember the password for a while, interact with smartcards, and figure out which pinentry program to show to the user. Importantly, it listens on a Unix domain socket, so it can be forwarded over connections like SSH with the `-R` remote listening setup.

The original motivation for my question was in the context of remote working: you get a computer somewhere, you can only work on the code via a remote connection, and you can't (as in, not supposed to) bring the code away from the remote connection. It is for these setups that `gpg-agent` forwarding works best: a hidden channel is established in addition to your session, and over that channel the remote `gpg` program talks to your local `gpg-agent`, and the `gpg-agent` retains the private keys while only providing the result to the remote computer.

But this could also work for air-gapped setups. I've tried opening two terminal panes, one on the remote computer with a `nc -Ul` listening on the Unix socket where the `gpg-agent` would normally live, and one on my local computer with `gpg-connect-agent`, and copying the commands back and forth between the two windows. I almost went through the entire signature transaction, and the only reason it failed is at the very last step, when executing `PKSIGN`, it produced a bunch of binary data that did not get copied over correctly in the clipboard.

[image: gpg-agent transaction]

So, the plan is:

1. On the untrusted computer, replace the standard `gpg-agent` program with one that responds with `OK`s until the `PKSIGN` command. When a signature operation is requested, the program pops up an alert containing the previous commands in a compressed text-only form.
2. A human copies the data on the screen into the trusted computer that holds the keys. There, a program replays the commands into the real `gpg-agent`, which performs the signature operation, and then returns a compressed text-only response.
3. The human then copies this data back into the untrusted computer. The pretend `gpg-agent` returns the response to the calling `gpg` program, which completes the signature.

This is basically similar to `gpg-agent` forwarding over SSH, except that the protocol is modified to require less back-and-forth interactions (since those require the attention of the human now).

---

This is of course very theoretical and very paranoid: the computer I'm working on is obviously not airgapped because I'd be remoting into it. A realistic solution for my problem is to use normal `gpg-agent` forwarding, and/or generate a new key to keep on the untrusted computer (perhaps signed by my main key, perhaps not).